# How to write jest unit test for a observable variable that's only used on template "Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined"?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a simple angular component that has a constructor and observable variable used on the html template. I am very new to creating jest unit tests and not sure why this doesn't work:

voice-summary.component.ts

```
export class VoiceSummaryComponent {
  vm$ = this._voiceService.accountDetails$.pipe(
    map(state => state.billingAccount)
  );

  constructor(private _voiceService: VoiceService) {}
}
```

voice-summary.spec.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { VoiceSummaryComponent } from './voice-summary.component';

@Injectable()
class MockService {}

describe('VoiceSummaryComponent', () => {
  let component: any;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    component = new VoiceSummaryComponent(new MockService() as any);
    component.vm$ = jest.fn();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    expect(component.vm$).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

2 Failures:

```
  ● VoiceSummaryComponent › should create

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined

      10 | })
      11 | export class VoiceSummaryComponent {
    > 12 |   vm$ = this._voiceService.accountDetails$.pipe(
         |                                            ^
      13 |     map(state => state.billingAccount)
      14 |   );
      15 | 


  ● VoiceSummaryComponent › should create

    expect(received).toBeTruthy()

    Received: undefined

      14 | 
      15 |   it('should create', () => {
    > 16 |     expect(component).toBeTruthy();
         |                       ^
      17 |     expect(component.vm$).toHaveBeenCalled();
      18 |   });
      19 | });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being my solution:

I needed to add a mock service object with the accountDetails$ observable obj into the beforeEach function.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { VoiceSummaryComponent } from './voice-summary.component';

describe('VoiceSummaryComponent', () => {
  let component: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const mockService = {
      accountDetails$: of({}),
    };
    component = new VoiceSummaryComponent(mockService as any);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```